# Creating and adding data in a linked Llist

Tags: c, arrays, data-structures, linked-list

I have started learning about Linked Lists, which through videos and multiple examples I have pretty much understood what a Linked List is and how it can be represented in a real life analogy. But when it comes to coding it I get lost I suppose through all the pointers I kind of get confused, it took a bit for me to get a stronger grasp on arrays so I assume it will be the same with Linked lists. So here is my code

```
/*
•   The program will use dynamic memory to create a singly linked list(NO ARRAYS PERMITTED)
•   The program will store unlimited number of student records(limited only by RAM).
•   A student record will consist of Student Name, Age, and GPA…you may need to add additional fields to make this work(Next).
•   The program will have a way for the user to add records(in order by name).You can assume that no two students have the same name.The list will always be in order.
•   The program will have a way for the user to display ALL records.
•   The program needs a way to quit.
*/

#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#pragma warning(disable: 4996)// disables warning
typedef struct{
    char name[40];
    int age;
    float gpa;
    struct NODE* next;
}NODE;
void addStudent();

int main(void){
    NODE* head = NULL;
    int userinput;
    printf("       **********************************\n");
    printf("       *        MENU                    *\n");
    printf("       *  1. Add Student                *\n");
    printf("       *  2. Display all student records*\n");
    printf("       *  3. Quit                       *\n");
    printf("       **********************************\n");
    scanf_s("%d%*[^\n]", &userinput); '\n' == getchar();
    switch (userinput)
    {
    case 1: do
    {
        addStudent(head);
        printf("Add another record? 1(y) 2(n)\n");
        scanf_s("%d%*[^\n]", &userinput); '\n' == getchar();
    } while (userinput == 1);
    break;

    }





    }

void addStudent(NODE* head){

    head = malloc(sizeof(NODE));
    if (head == NULL)
    {
        return;
    }
    NODE * current = head;
    printf("Please Enter student name:\n");
    fgets(current->name, 40, stdin);
    printf("Enter student age:\n");
    scanf("%d%*[^\n]", &current->age); '\n' == getchar();
    printf("Enter student gpa:\n");
    scanf("%f%*[^\n]", &current->gpa); '\n' == getchar();
    current->next;
    current->next = NULL;

    while (current != NULL){
        current = head;
        printf("%s\n", current->name);
        printf("%d\n", current->age);
        printf("%0.2f\n", current->gpa);
        current = current->next;
    }
}
```

When I compile, it will always print the head I assume its because of `current = head` within the while loop, I understand why its printing the head over but I am lost on how to arrange this code So that I can create a new node when I add and print all the nodes, through the loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you never create new nodes to add to the list but always just updating the head. In order to make it work you should:

1. Allocate a new `NODE`,

   ```
   NODE *newNode = malloc(sizeof(NODE));
   ```
2. Load the data into this node

   ```
   printf("Please Enter student name:\n");
   fgets(&newNode->name, 40, stdin);
   printf("Enter student age:\n");
   scanf("%d%*[^\n]", &newNode->age); '\n' == getchar();
   printf("Enter student gpa:\n");
   scanf("%f%*[^\n]", &newNode->gpa); '\n' == getchar();
   ```
3. Update the node to point to the node currently pointed by the HEAD

   ```
   newNode->next = head
   ```
4. Update the head to point to the new Node

   ```
   head = newNode;
   ```

Comment: Step 3 and 4 is where I'm kind of having problems, isnt `newNode->next = head` pointing new node towards head, and then `head = newNode;` is setting newnode as the head? so is this how you would add a node to the beginning of the list? What if I want to add more to the list would head become the tail eventually?

Comment: In the current implementation you indeed add new nodes to the beginning of the list (which for singly-linked list can be used as a Stack implementation). If you'd like to add the nodes to the end of the list (Queue like list) than you'll have to store also a pointer to the last element (the tail) of the list and link this element to the new element you'd like to add.

Comment: Okay I understand, then how would one go with adding items any where else like in the middle of the list?

Comment: **[a]** Create a new node N, **[b]** find node X after which the new node should be added; let's call the node X is currently connected to Y, **[c]** link N to Y (i.e. `N->next = X->next`), **[d]** link X to N (i.e. `X->next = N`).